# How to get grandparent of a given category

Tags: categories

Just wondering what the best way to get the top-most level category (grandparent) of a given category assuming it has one?

Example structure:

Operating Systems
- Mac
- - Mountain Lion
- Windows
- - Windows XP

I want to be able to somehow get the ID of the "Operating Systems" category from within the Windows XP category.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a simple function to do this each time you need to. Here's an example I found on [this website](http://alex.leonard.ie/2011/04/20/wordpress-get-id-of-top-level-parent-category/).

```
function pa_category_top_parent_id( $catid ) {
    while( $catid ) {
        $cat = get_category( $catid ); // get the object for the catid
        $catid = $cat->category_parent; // assign parent ID (if exists) to $catid
        // the while loop will continue whilst there is a $catid
        // when there is no longer a parent $catid will be NULL so we can assign our $catParent
        $catParent = $cat->cat_ID;
    }
    return $catParent;
}
```

Then you can use this function anywhere like so:

```
$catid = get_query_var( 'cat' );
echo pa_category_top_parent_id( $catid );
```

Reading the comments in the code it is pretty self-explanatory. Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome! I was thinking along the lines of this. But you nailed it! Thanks!